# What's a better way to detect negative numbers without using a literal?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Normally to detect a negative number, you just do `if(x < 0) ...`. But what's the best way to do this *without* the hard-coded literal? It's not the value that I need to avoid, it's the datatype. I am looking for something in the style of `<algorithm>`.

I have the following solution, but is there a better way? Something tells me this is not as efficient as possible.

```
template<typename T>
inline bool is_negative(const T& n)
{
    return n < (n - n);
}
```

I want to use the same restrictions that  uses. So it's fine to require that `T` implement arithmetic operators, but nothing more specific / specialized than that.

Otherwise we could solve this by just requiring that `T` implement:

- `bool operator <(int)`
- `T()` (default constructor which we assume equals 0)
- Or why not just require `bool IsNegative()`

It's just for my own curiosity; not for use in any project.

Comment: The best way is `if(x < 0)`, because that converts to one assembler's instruction.

Comment: VJo: that's not generic. It's reasonable to expect `T` to implement `bool operator <(const T&) const`, but not `bool operator <(int)`.

Comment: did you mean `inline bool is_negative(const T& n)` ?

Comment: @tenfour: I may be wrong, but the term *negative* only applies to numeric types.  The compiler can convert zero (0) to any numeric type, e.g. 0.0 for floats and doubles.  So why is `(x < 0)` not generic?

Comment: Because what if `T` is a `TimeSpan`? You cannot assume `T` is comparable to an integer.

Comment: "negative" has a very simple meaning. Whether your domain is ℕ, ℚ, or ℝ, < defines a total order. All these sets contain 0, and negative is the subset `{x | x<0}`. The subset {x | x>5} also has operator<, but no 0, so the term "negative" doesn't have a meaning for that subset. This means the question here is fundamentally nonsensical. If the type T has negative numbers, it must also include 0 in its domain, and `T()` is the cannonical C++ representation.

Comment: @MSalters: Of course, but the question is then: How do you generically represent the constant value `0`? The practical solution is the accepted answer; I should just assume there is a conversion from `(int)0`. In practice, this will work. In theory, it's possible that there's some number class that doesn't have a conversion from `int`. For example imagine `class temperature` which requires F or C to be indicated, thus there's no conversion from a simple integer. And a default construction would not necessarily represent the correct 0.

Comment: @tenfour: Your temperature °F/°C example, like my set `{x | x>5}` is an example of a set which does have a less-than ordening, but no 0, and _therefore_ no negative numbers. (A temperature scale purely in °C or purely in °F _does_ have a 0 and _therefore_ negative values). See also cardinal vs ordinal numbers.

Comment: True. But it doesn't address the 'issue' of assuming `T` has a conversion from `(int)0`. In practice though not really much of an issue. That's why the case is closed on this question :P Thanks for the input though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with `if (x < T(0))` ?

Since you are seemingly interested in numeric types, a very natural requirement for such types is that they provide a constructor which takes a fundamental type (int, or double).

I find it more natural that default construction, which may not exist, or have different semantics (undefined, not-a-number, etc. An example is the time classes from eg. `boost::posix_time` which default construct to invalid dates)

Comment: Why do you assume `T` has a constructor which takes an `int` arg?

Answer (score 4):

```
return n < T();
```

(Now I wonder why you have that restriction).

Comment: Note that this also works for native types - int() == 0 in this context and so on.

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific about the restrictions / assumptions about `T`. Is it reasonable to assume that `T` has a default constructor, and that it is functionally "zero"? IOW would this expectation fly in <algorithm>?

Comment: On my compiler this produces a warning for `unsigned int` saying that it can *never* be less than zero. :-)

Comment: @tenfour, the arithmetic types work like that.  If you want to use other types which mostly mimic the rest of the behavior of arithmetic types, I don't think the added requirement is unreasonable. Probably less than operator<(int) (are you sure that unsigned/signed will works like you want? I think so but I tend to be careful when mixing them) or is_negative (you'd need to provide it for arithmetic types).

Comment: @tenfour: what does it mean for a type to be negative if it doesn't have some concept of "zero"?  I think that it would be reasonable for the template's 'contract' to include either that the default constructor be equivalent to zero, or that the type be able to convert an int 0 to whatever that type considers a zero equivalent.  I think you should be able to use SFINAE to allow either interface contract conditions to be met (as long as the type provides at least one of those options).

Comment: Yea that's true; I think in that case the most reasonable answer is @Alexandre C's solution, because it's more explicit about the concept of "zero".

Answer (score 0):

Checking if something is less than literal zero is right solution.  It's the most clear about your intent.  It's also the most efficient, but please stop thinking about efficiency when you are checking if a number is negative.  That's a bad thing.

Comment: It's purely theoretical. And it's not a number, it's a `T`, and `T` is not compatible with `int`.